# Slick Lifted Embedding: working with CURRENT_DATE (from PostgreSQL)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala, slick

I am struggling to use CURRENT_DATE from PostgreSQL with Slick lifted embedding. I want to use it as a default value for a column, and to use it for calculating delays:

```
CREATE TABLE Test(id serial PRIMARY KEY, updated date DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE);

SELECT * FROM Test WHERE CURRENT_DATE - updated > 8;
```

are both valid SQL commands with PostgreSQL. How can I emulate them with Slick Lifted embedding? I tried to declare this in Scala:

```
def current_date = SimpleFunction.nullary[java.sql.Date]("CURRENT_DATE")
```

However, this returns a `Column[Date]` although `O.Default(…)` expects a `Date`, and it does not recognize the `-` operation in `filter(…)`.

Answer (score 1):

Not supported right now. We have a PR in the queue. Probably arrives in 2.1 . https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/213